# Writing CSV data to XLS file in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a CSV file and want to Write data from CSV file to XLS file. But here is the tricky part, a new CSV file gets generated after few seconds and again I need to write the CSV data into the same Excel file that has been already generated, but now the new data will be added into new row.

This is not an homework Assignment, I have a Machine Which is generating a new csv file after few seconds. And I want my Excel sheet to be updated with the new file CSV data.

I am looking for solution or partial solution in python.

Thank you

Comment: Is it an long running process where a csv is generated every few seconds ?

Comment: It gets generated into a directory, I came to know that there is an API Watchdog that can look for new files generated. And yeah the CSV keep on getting generated till I dont shutdown the machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, the workflow will probably be something like this using pandas:

```
new_data = pandas.read_csv('new_data.csv', header=0)
all_data = pandas.read_excel('file://excel_file.xlsx')
combined = all_data.append(new_data)
combined.to_excel('excel_file.xlsx')
```

Of course you may need to mess with some of the parameters to match up everything with your data, and possibly have this looping so it is always getting the latest changes and adding them.

---

**Useful docs that will assist:**

- [Reading CSV Files into Pandas Dataframe](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)
- [Reading Excel Files into Pandas Dataframe](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html)
- [Joining two dataframes into one](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html)
- [Writing dataframe to Excel file](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html)

Comment: Thank you for the response, but I don't want to do this tedious task of appending all data again and again. I am looking for something Where only the existing Excel file is appended with new data only.

Comment: @ViralParmar Could you please explain what you mean? This reads the existing excel file and appends the new data from the CSV? Does the CSV contain all the data as well but has new rows added every few seconds?

Comment: Every time a new CSV is generated with Few rows, and I want those new rows to be appended to my existing XLS file.

Comment: @ViralParmar Right, these four lines of code could be called every time that the API Watchdog notices a new CSV file. Since the CSV only contains new rows, and the excel sheet (which you can keep writing over) has everything prior, the append will only add those new rows, and it would save be saved as an excel file with the same name.

Comment: Do you have any idea of what to do with the header in each CSV file? I mean I only need data. I dont want header again and again from the newly generated CSV file . Header as in Column name.

Comment: @ViralParmar set header=None in to_excel

Comment: @Viral Parmar the part that says header=0  sets the header of the dataframe to row 0 (which has all the column names) of the csv. The to_excel method may have something similar, I would check the docs. Then when you append, as long as the headers match up, the new dataframe that the append method creates keeps the headers from the original (Excel) and appends only the data

Comment: @JoeD Thanks Mate! I'm also Looking at to_excel method , In case you come across any updates regarding to_excel method then please do post it here.

Comment: @mujjiga Thank you ! I will surely Check into It and will let you know !

Comment: @JoeD  The Code is overwriting the first row and when I set header = none in to_excel it omit the header and add only data to excel file.

Comment: @Viral Parmar try header=0 instead of header=None

Comment: @JoeD I want the header for the first time from the first CSV file and then i don't want header from the further generated csv files. I hope making header = 0 will solve my problem .

Comment: For the first time just save the csv to excel as is...on future runs the headers will only be used from that excel file. Or you could switch the append order and do new_data.append(all_data) (but that puts the new data at the top of the Excel file every time)